# How can I create Saved Search on 'Case Status List' standard List (Record Type - supportcasestatus) in NetSuite or any other way to access the list

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, saved-searches

I'm trying to access 'Case Status List' like
var caseSearchObj = search.create({
type: 'supportcasestatus',
columns:
[
search.createColumn({ name: "internalid" }),
]
});

but it shows the error record not exist

I'm trying to access 'Case Status List' like
var caseSearchObj = search.create({
type: 'supportcasestatus',
columns:
[
search.createColumn({ name: "internalid" }),
]
});

but it shows the error record not exist

I want to store some list values into the custome select field.